# AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds doens´t work after I updated to Xamarin.Forms 5.0

Tags: xaml, xamarin, absolutelayout

After I updated to Xamarin.Forms 5.0 this line of code has been broken:

```
<AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle">
        <On Platform="Android">0.5,0.49,0.4,0.5</On>
        <On Platform="iOS">0.5,0.52,0.4,0.5</On>
     </OnPlatform>
</AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: "this line of code has been broken" -- how so? can you share any errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

About setting AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds by platform, you can try to following code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout Margin="20">
    <BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{OnPlatform Android='0,10,200,5', iOS='0,0,.5,.5'}" Color="Silver">          
    </BoxView>
   
</AbsoluteLayout>
```